# Get Value from Spinner and pass spinner value as parameter in json query Android

Tags: android, json, spinner, android-spinner

What i want is:

1]I have json service : http://abcd.in/getAllUsers.php

2]I have a spinner for filter option i.e 1] spinner for selecting type of user

3] I have Full list of user.

4] but when i try to use spinner list is empty

5] I want query like this :http://abcd.in/getAllUsers.php?UserType=simple

How i can achieve this from spinner.
When i try to get value of spinner like this

```
param = "?UserType=";
        Log.d("param", param);
        url = url + param+spinnervalue;
```

List view is empty.

What i have Done is :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    ListView lv;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    Spinner spUserType, spOccupation;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_directory);

  // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> userType = new ArrayList<String>();
        userType.add("vip");
        userType.add("simple");
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, userType);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 spUserType.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


  @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        // Showing selected spinner item
     /*   Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("UserType", item.toString());*/

        param = "?UserType=";
        Log.d("param", param);
        url = url + param+item;

        JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
        JSONObject rootObj = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = rootObj.getJSONArray(array);

            Log.d("array", "" + jsonArray.length());

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject job = obj.getJSONObject("User");
             /*   JSONArray jsonArray2 = rootObj.getJSONArray("User");
                JSONObject obj2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);*/

                Log.d("obj", obj.toString());

                String pp2 = job.getString(pp);
                String uName2 = job.getString(uName);

                String bio1 = job.getString(bio);
                String email1 = job.getString(email);
                String time = job.getString(timeBlock);

                String flat = job.getString(flatRatePrice);


                Log.d("pp", uName2);
                // Log.d("tag",flag2.toString() );


                map.put("Profilepicture", pp2);

                map.put("Username", uName2);
                map.put("Biodata", bio1);
                map.put("Email", email1);

                map.put("Timeblock", time);
                map.put("Flatrateprice", flat);

              /*  map.put("Occupation",occupation);
                map.put("Email",email);

                Log.d("occupation",Occupation.toString());*/


                Log.d("map", map.toString());
                arraylist.add(map);


            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);



        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arraylist);
        Log.d("list", arraylist.toString());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
```

Comment: Check my edited Question

Comment: change your param= UserType instead of ?UserType=

Comment: 100% not working @ Amarbir Singh

Comment: your url(http://abcd.in/getAllUsers.php?UserType=simple) is leaked check it first on rest client

Comment: it is not aa proper url i have provided. it is dummy(fake) url

Comment: you use ``spUserType.setAdapter(dataAdapter);`` , but where you declare ``spUserType`` ??

Answer (score 1):

Add values to the spinner.

```
this.arraySpinner = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then use a on ItemSelected listener

```
s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        String items = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Log.i("Selected item : ", items);
        //use your logic here
        param = "?UserType=";
        Log.d("param", param);
        url = url + param+spinnervalue;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}

});
```

Comment: Thank u.. but it happens for first time only.. when i select second option list is empty

Comment: You should set the list adapter in onCreate

Comment: If i set the list adapter onCreate then how to fetch json

Comment: You should post your code for that. You can use global variables to access them in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<>();
userList.add("simple");
userList.add("small");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, userList);
your_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          String spinnervalue = your_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
          //then use this for your purpose
          param = "?UserType=";
          Log.d("param", param);
          url = url + param+spinnervalue;
          }
       }

       @Override
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
       }
});
```

Comment: Thank u.. but it happens for first time only.. when i select second option list is empty

Comment: you can try my answer and remove adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after using lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: can you explain in detail what do you mean by "it happens for first time only.. when i select second option list is empty" did you check api url?

Comment: First time means ,by default spinner has value "vip", so list of vip user comes, but when i select "simple" ,list gets empty

Comment: did you check response in broswer or is there any error any error in api while fetching list of simple users?

Comment: list﹕ [ ], now can u get it

Comment: i mean to say that if response in also empty in browser then there is error in api otherwise error in app

Comment: I just need to refresh my list.. after selecting spinner value list is not getting filed. no error in program. I just need to reload the list

Comment: can you give url when second option is selected?

Comment: when i select next option . paramter would be smthing like this  param﹕ ?UserType=. But it should be param﹕ ?UserType=simple or param﹕ ?UserType=vip

Comment: can you give original url?